# How to write time in excel in the format 00:00.00

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I type my time into Excel what I typed is different from what Excel says I've typed (see orange arrows in image). Does this matter? Will it affect me when it comes to making my table into a graph? As I am trying to say 00:00.00 which I’m guessing is the same as mm:ss.ms in stopwatch time.

[image: Pic of excel file]

Answer (score 0):

The default time format of Excel varies depending on your Locale.

To change it, select a range, then right-click and choose Format Cells, which should open on the Numbers tab (choose Numbers if it does not). Then, choose Time in the left pane of the dialog box, choose the desired format in the right side pane, then click OK.

[image: Here's an illustration]